# Keep go to Database Error 2 in my php script

Tags: php

This is my shipmentrequest.php

```
<?php

require("config.inc.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {

if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['mobilenumber']) || empty($_POST['address']) || empty($_POST['city'])  || empty($_POST['postcode']) || empty($_POST['state'])) {

    // Create some data that will be the JSON response 
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Please Enter the required marked ** field.";

    die(json_encode($response));
}
else if (strlen($_POST['postcode']) < 5 || strlen($_POST['postcode']) >= 6) {
$response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Your postcode should be only 5 numbers.";
die(json_encode($response));               
}

$query = "INSERT INTO shipmentrequest ( name, mobilenumber, address, city, postcode, state) VALUES ( :receivername, :receivermobilenumber, :receiveraddress, :receivercity, :receiverpostcode, :receiverstate) ";

//Again, we need to update our tokens with the actual data:
$query_params = array(
    ':name' => $_POST['name'],
    ':mobilenumber' => $_POST['mobilenumber'],
    ':address' => $_POST['address'],
':city' => $_POST['city'],
    ':postcode' => $_POST['postcode'],
':state' => $_POST['state']
);

//time to run our query, and create the user
try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
    //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

    //or just use this use this one:
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

//If we have made it this far without dying, we have successfully added
//a new user to our database.  We could do a few things here, such as 
//redirect to the login page.  Instead we are going to echo out some
//json data that will be read by the Android application, which will login
//the user (or redirect to a different activity, I'm not sure yet..)
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Shipping Service Succesfully Requested!";
echo json_encode($response);

//for a php webservice you could do a simple redirect and die.
//header("Location: login.php"); 
//die("Redirecting to login.php");


} else {
?>
<h1>Shipment Request</h1> 
<form action="shipmentrequest.php" method="post">
    Name:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" /> 
    <br /><br />     
    Mobile Number:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="mobilenumber" value="" /> 
    <br /><br />
    Address:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="address" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    City:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="city" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    Postcode:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="postcode" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    State:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="state" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Request Service" /> 
</form>
<?php
}

?>
```

I dont know why even I filled up my postcode textfield with 5 numbers only, It will just jump to the exceptional handling which is... `Database Error2. Please Try Again!` Can anyone tell me why it will go to the catch statement?

Comment: Have you tried to echo the *actual* error message?  It might have more information than just `"Please Try Again"`.  Commenting out the error message while you are testing doesn't really help.

Comment: "*die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());*". Sooo.. What does it output?

Comment: I just don't know why it will just just to the `catch (PDOException $ex)` even I already fill up all the information correctly

Comment: @RocketHazmat, then how should I really do to need more information?

Comment: @Nick: Don't comment out the `die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());` line.

Comment: @h2ooooooo The message is `Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined`

Comment: @Nick: Because in your prepared statement you have `:receivername`, but in your array, you are sending `:name`.

Comment: @Nick: Either change the keys of your `$query_params` to `':receivername' => $_POST['name']`, etc.  Or change your `$query` to use `:name`, etc.  The names in the `$query` need to match those `$query_params`, how else would PDO know what to put where in your query?  The actual field names in your database are fine, it's just the placeholders.

Comment: ohh? even my `:receivername` is one attribute in my database, if I change `$query` to use`:name`, and `$query_params` to `':name' => $_POST['name']` does PDO knows the :name is meant for :receivername for my database?

Comment: @RocketHazmat  
I change it already but now new message which is Failed to run query: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'` Is it means my database don't have such column?

Comment: @Nick: That does sound like the case.  Check what the columns in your `shipmentrequest` table are actually named.

Comment: @Nick: All PDO does is replace `:name` in your query string with the value you've told it.  That's it.  Which field in your database it uses depends on your INSERT query.  The field names after the table name are where you are inserting, the VALUES need to be in that order.

Comment: @Nick: Then `name` is not the name of your field, its `receivername`.  Then it should be `INSERT INTO shipmentrequest(receivername, ...) VALUES (:name, ...);`.

Comment: I found it, where should I correct the code which is at `$query = "INSERT INTO shipmentrequest ( name, mobilenumber, address, city, postcode, state) VALUES`. I change the `name` to `receivername` and others, then the problem solves , Thanks for the guidance anyway

Answer (score 2):

Looks like those tokens in `$query` doesn't match with what you put in `$query_params` array:

```
   VALUES (:receivername, :receivermobilenumber, :receiveraddress, :receivercity, :receiverpostcode, :receiverstate)
```

Answer (score 1):

binding parameter name values are not matched.

it should be `:name, :mobilenumber, etc` instead of `:receivername, :receivermobilenumber, etc`

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO shipmentrequest ( name, mobilenumber, address, city, postcode, state) VALUES ( :name, :mobilenumber, :address, :city, :postcode, :state) ";
```

Comment: @Nick: This has nothing to do with your "database variable".  These "variables" are just so PDO knows what to replace with what.